# wxMaxima assertion failed: "lang == wxLANGUAGE_DEFAULT"

Tags: maxima, wxmaxima

Installed wxmaxima from the ubuntu 18.04 repository after a fresh install of ubuntu. However I get the following error:

```
An assertion failed:

../src/common/intl.cpp(1071): assert "lang == wxLANGUAGE_DEFAULT" failed 
in IsAvailable(): No info for a valid language?
```

The backtrace is as follows:

```
wxLocale::IsAvailable(int)
MyApp::OnInit()
wxEntry(int&, wchar_t**)
main
__libc_start_main
_start
```

Unticking `Show this dialog next time` doesn't help. The warning shows up next time again. If I click `Continue` wxmaxima works normally. Help required so that this warning doesn't show up every time I open wxmaxima.

Comment: Hi, on looking at the source code in intl.cpp, I see that wxMaxima looks at the environment variables LC_ALL, LC_CTYPE, and LANG to determine the value of lang. What is the output of `echo LC_ALL=$LC_ALL LC_CTYPE=$LC_CTYPE LANG=$LANG` on your system?

Comment: The output of `echo LC_ALL=$LC_ALL LC_CTYPE=$LC_CTYPE LANG=$LANG` is `LC_ALL= LC_CTYPE= LANG=en_IN`

Comment: @RobertDodier: Supprisingly the output of `locale` command is `LANG=en_IN
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_IN"
LC_NUMERIC="en_IN"
LC_TIME="en_IN"
LC_COLLATE=en_IN.utf8
LC_MONETARY="en_IN"
LC_MESSAGES="en_IN"
LC_PAPER="en_IN"
LC_NAME="en_IN"
LC_ADDRESS="en_IN"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_IN"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_IN"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_IN"
LC_ALL=`

Comment: OK, thanks for this information. It appears that only LANG has a value on your system (namely en_IN) and not LC_ALL nor LC_CTYPE. Given that, my advice is to change the value of LANG. Can you launch wxMaxima from a terminal? If so, try: `LANG=en_US wxmaxima` or `export LANG=en_US; wxmaxima` My guess is that wxMaxima doesn't know what to do with en_IN.

Comment: Okay. Even before I tried to follow your advice, I had installed wxmaxima version 17.10.1 by downloading and compiling from source. This version didn't have the above problem. I had also uninstalled the ubuntu version 18.02.0.

Comment: In order to follow your advice I uninstalled the older version and reinstalled the newer version from ubuntu repository. Voila - no problem. Now I am confused as to how the problem got fixed. I didn't even have to follow your advice.

Comment: Should I mark this as "Solved", even though I don't know how it got solved?

Comment: Hmm, I wonder what is happening. About marking it solved, I'm not sure. I can see reasons to mark it solved and reasons to not mark it. All in all, I'm glad to hear  you got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solved my problem on another machine.

Edit > Configure > Worksheet > 
Untick "Use centered dot character for multiplication".